# http is not working in case of Web socket UI Client

Tags: sockets, websocket

I am using Websocket Programming in my Application 
This is my Websocket Client from UI Screen .

When i use the protocol ws , It is contacting the server .

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:"+<%=request.getLocalPort()%>+"/Ravi/hello-html5";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

But if replace ws with http , its not cotatcing to the server .

That is with this url

```
http://localhost:"+<%=request.getLocalPort()%>+"/Ravi/hello-html5";
```

This is my web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloHtml5</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.Html5Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloHtml5</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello-html5/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

Please let me kow why http is not working ??

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you call new WebSocket with a http uri?  Is SyntaxError thrown or does your websocket's onerror or onclose callback run?

The [JavaScript API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#the-websocket-interface) and [websocket spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) are unclear on which url schemes are acceptable.  If SyntaxError is being thrown, your browser is rejecting http as an invalid scheme.  Other browsers may behave differently.  If one of your callbacks is being run, the server is rejecting the connection.  Other servers (you don't say which one you're using) may behave differently.